# Bind combobox selection to currentrow of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I successfully populate a datagridview from an external db.  I am then able to add and populate a combobox to the dgv (column[10]).  However, when I chose a value from the combobox, it appears to populate for all rows in the dgv when I try to write back to the db (the last value selected is stored for each row).  The dgv in the form appears as I WANT it to look (I can select different values for each row).

```
private void bUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newValue= "";
        string lineKey = "";
        int newValueLen = 0;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var newValueValue = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value;
            if (newValueValue == null)
            {
                newValueLen = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                newValueLen = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString().Length;
            }
            if (newValueLen > 0)
            {
                newValue= dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                lineKey = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                conn.Open();
                string sqlUpdate = "Insert into tErrorLog select 'newValue = " + newValue + "; LineKey = " + lineKey + "; Cycle = " + i.ToString() + "; newValueLen = " + newValueLen.ToString() + "'";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, conn);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                newValue= "";
                lineKey = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

When I change at least one value, I get 44 entries (this is the number of records in the dgv) into tErrorLog, all with the same value (except the cycle number).  I am sure I use too many variables for newValue, but I was trying lots of permutations.  I will clean this up once I get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dataGridView1.Rows[i]` `dataGridView1.CurrentRow`. `CurrentRow` will return currently selected row, so you saving 44 times values of same row.

Suggest always use `SqlParameter` for creating sql queries and passing values there. When you concatenate values with query string you become vulnerable for sql injection and your queries do not use full power of sql server (compiled query plans for example)

```
private void bUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var newValueValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i.Cells[10].Value;
        if (newValueValue == null)
        {
            newValueLen = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            newValueLen = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString().Length;
        }
        if (newValueLen > 0)
        {
            // Instantiate values here, so you don't need to reset them every time
            var newValue= dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            var lineKey = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            var logValues = 
                $"newValue = {newValue}; LineKey = {lineKey}; Cycle = {i}; newValueLen = {newValueLen}";                

            var query = "INSERT INTO tErrorLog SELECT @LogValues";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                var parameter = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@LogValues", // Should be same as in query
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, // Use actual type from your database
                    Size = 300, // Use actual size of your column in database
                    Value = logValues
                };
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                conn.Open
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run this, I get the actual string "newValue = {newValue}; LineKey = {lineKey}; Cycle = {i}; newValueLen = {newValueLen}" to appear in my db.  But at least it runs the appropriate number of times.  When I create actual parameters for each of the variables ({lineKey} to @LineKey, for example) the new parameters are not populated with the values.  I still get the actual string "@LineKey" instead of value from the dgv.

Comment: I reverted back to my original code, but changing "CurrentRow" to "Row[I]" and the code worked perfectly.  Thanks a lot!!